# Javafx image is not found in fxml

Tags: javafx

I have searched many possible questions and answers but I could not get any solution. 
I have my fxml as,

```
<Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Profile">
    <items>
       <MenuItem id="loadProfile" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Load Profile" style="-fx-graphic: url('../res/icon_open_32x32.png');" />
    </items>
</Menu>
```

and my project structure is:

```
com.vion.myapp.view
    - Application.fxml
com.vion.myapp.res
    - icon_open_32x32.png
```

Why I my menuitem is not finding the image and displaying it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute path to resource: `/com/vion/myapp/res/icon_open_32x32.png`.

Seems like in case of `../res/icon_open_32x32.png` current path is not defined or not the equals to `/com/vion/myapp/view`.

Comment: Using the absolute path as you suggested has worked. Can it be used as a perfect solution , or there is still something else.